# Getting attributes from intersecting lines to label generated intersection point?

Tags: intersection, network, line

I have an urban road network (as a feature class), consisting of only polylines. I have to make a database of all the intersections between the streets.

As I generate those intersection points, I don't know how to address the names of the streets as an attribute for each point. For example, if I have streets with names "1" and "2", the point "x" at their intersection should be named "1,2" or so, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: How do you intend to distinguish between the intersection of "1" with "2" and "2" with "1"?  What should happen if the road changes names at the intersection, or if more than two roads meet at an intersection, or if a road dead-ends?  All these cases need to be covered in your design.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have created your points, you can perform an Intersect or Spatial Join (one-to-many) of your roads to your points. This should give you the name attributes of each road meeting at the intersection as attributes of the points. You can then label the points with those attributes. For more specific instructions you'll need to tell us what software you're using.